# Vagrant & Virtualbox - How To Mark VM As Provisioned

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

A little while ago vagrant managed to loose association with my virtualbox VM after a system crash, meaning that whenever I tried to bring vagrant up it was trying to create a new box.

After reading round a few blog posts I've managed to re-attach the VM by setting the ID of the virtualbox VM in this file '.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id'.

The only problem is that while it now doesnt recreate the box, it doesn't recognise that the VM has already been provisioned so re-runs all the init scripts - and I really want to avoid this.

I know I can bring the box back up with the --no-provision flag, but is there any way I can just mark the VM as already provisioned as at some point I'll forget to add the flag and wipe out any task specific config I've added to my VM?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you just destroy the box and start over? The whole point of vagrant is you should be able to just delete it all and re-provision it again to get back to the state you need. If you're installing stuff and configuring the VM manually with out matching those changes in your provisioning scripts you may as well leave vagrant out of the equation entirely and stick with just VBox.

Comment: Im working on a really large system with quite a few multiple apps - kind of a micro service architecture.  Usually to work on a specific issue I only run the services / apps I need to complete whatever I'm working on.

Comment: To run the full stack would be almost impossible on a single machine  (its HUGE - about 70 local grails plugins, and 12 grails apps and 5 std java ones thrown plus 15 DBs - 30Gb of data).  The apps & services I don't run get mapped to a staging env via apache rewrites rules and inline plugin settings are applied for what I want to work on.  A re-provisoin takes at least 30 mins so is impractical to do per task - so I keep a base setup in vagrant and just poke some apache & run-time config depending on what I need to do and its this type of thing that i'd want to avoid overwriting in a crash.